# Find the smallest possible value of the integer part of the arithmetic mean

Tags: number-theory

> On the board are written distinct natural numbers whose integer part of their arithmetic mean is unknown but its fractional part is $0.2016$. Find the smallest possible value of the integer part of the arithmetic mean.

Let the $n$ natural numbers be $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, so that $$\dfrac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n} = A+0.2016 = A+\dfrac{126}{625}$$ and so $126n \equiv 0 \pmod{625}$. Thus, $n = 625k$ where $k$ is a positive integer. We also have $$A = \dfrac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}-\dfrac{126}{625} = \dfrac{625(x_1+\cdots+x_n)-126n}{625n}.$$ How can we minimize $A$?

**Edit:** How would I solve the question if each of the natural numbers must be distinct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is just $A = 1$. With $n = 625$, we let 126 of the $x_i$'s be equal to 2 and the rest be equal to 1. Then the arithmetic mean is $\dfrac{625 + 126}{625} = 1 + \dfrac{126}{625}$. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of this problem, "natural numbers" clearly means positive integers (some people include zero in the set "natural numbers" but not in the context of this problem).

So the naive reasoning is that their must be $625k$ numbers on the board, with $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, and their sum must be $m\cdot 625k + 126k$ with  $m\in\Bbb Z$.
But $m \geq 1$ since the average of a set of numbers is always $\geq$ the minimum of that set.  And we can acheive $k=1,m=1$ by having the set be $499$ copies of the number $1$ and $126$ copies of the number $2$.

So the naive answer is $1$, but that seems too easy.

I prefer to look deeper:

> **Why** would you be able to determine the fractional part, but not the integer part, of the average?

The simplest answer to that is to say that one of the digits on the blackboard is smudged and illegible.  Then in order for that digit to have no influence on the answer, it must be the $10,000$ digit since $625$ divides $10,000$ but not $1,000$.  So the minimum average comes when we have $625$ numbers, one of which is between $?0000$ and $?0126$ (where the smudged $?$ stands for some digit from $1$ to $9$ and will turn out to be $1$ for the minimum average), and the remaining numbers are all $1$a and $2$a such that the sum is $10751$.

The integer part of the average is then $17$.